# Not getting correct path of file in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am new to Angular . When the user uploads a file, I want to get the file location . But I am getting a path value like this (The actual location is D:\Games\example.docx):

```
C:\fakepath\example.docx
```

The below is my code:

```
 onFileSelected(event){
    
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedFile= <File>event.target.files[0];
    console.log(event.target.value);

    
    this.addSftpModel.selectedFile=this.selectedFile;
    
    
  }
```

How can I get the original location of file uploaded

Comment: In my experience, you can't get it. You have to work with the file event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the full path of the file through a browser application. If you could, you could do whatever you want on the filesystem of the client, so it's normal that it's not accessible.

I don't know why you need the real path, but if you only need the file, the fakepath do the job.

Comment: I need to send this file using REST and also store the location from where it was uploaded

Comment: You can send the file as a FormData like in this example https://nehalist.io/uploading-files-in-angular2/, but for the path it's not possible to get the real path.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get a full path of the `input type=file` because it will create a vulnerability. You can [read here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#fakepath-srsly) for more detail.